# how can i install and set environment for aglets in ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: ant, distributed-computing, distributed, agent

I have to Design of distributed application using Mobile Agent on Aglet Platform. I tried to install the aglets platform(aglets-2.5-gamma)-

```
$aglets-alpha-2.5/bin> ant install-home
```

> Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!
>   Build failed

`$aglets-alpha-2.5/bin>agletsd -p 6000`

> agletsd: command not found

Comment: You are going to have to clarify a bit more about what you are doing, what you want to do, and what problems you are having. All we see here is that you don't have an ant script in a directory, and your shell can't find "agletsd". Bear in mind that "." may not be on your PATH, so your second command might be `./agletsd ...`

Comment: Well first of all it looks like your Ant install script is either in a different location or has a file name other than build.xml (Ant's default). Could you run `ls` in that directory so we can see what's there?

Comment: thanks! ./agletsd is working instead of agletsd -p 6000